# How can I offer recurring payments on an event registration form?

Tags: wordpress, civievent, civicontribute, profile, caldera-forms

My nonprofit has an online course that we plan to treat as an event as we get set up with CiviCRM. We currently use GravityForms on WordPress to offer registrants the option of a payment plan where they choose the number of months. We'd like to do that as we switch to CiviCRM. It looks like recurring payments would be a good fit but I have yet to find a way to include fields from `civicrm_contribution_recur` in an event registration form.

I've explored doing this through Caldera Forms but we use Stripe and the CF plugin for Stripe sends users off the page to a Stripe page, which we'd rather not do. It would be nice to do this all within CiviCRM. The necessary fields and underlying functionality are all there but so far I haven't figured out how to access them for this use.

Any pointers about how to approach this would be greatly appreciated. I'm willing to do some programming if necessary but would like to get better oriented first.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you seem to know programming, take a look at the code that Webform Civicrm Integration uses. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm They allow for installments which takes the total and divides it by number of months the user enters. Looking at how they do it might give you some ideas on how to do it on Garvity forms.

Comment: seeing various approaches to deposit/partial eg https://github.com/lcdservices/biz.lcdservices.registrationdeposit and https://github.com/backoffice/BOT-Partial-Payment-Extension. not offering a recommendation for either, just adding as a note here.